# Any idiom or phrase to describe the opposite of "love me, love my dog"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, idiom-requests

In English, there is an idiom called "**Love me, love my dog**" of which  ***Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary*** gives the following definition: (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/love-me-love-my-dog)

> said to warn someone that if they want to be in a relationship with
>   you, they must be willing to accept everything about you

I think this idiom can also be applicable to other not-in-a-relation situations, say.

> If you truly like your teaching job, you must be able to stand
>   students' naughtiness and once-in-a-while mischief, because love me, love my dog.

- Is my understanding about other not-in-a-relation situations correct?
- This is mainly what I want to ask. Any idiom or phrase that can
  describe the opposite of "**Love me, love my dog**" with the meaning:

> said to describe the situation in which if you hate something or
>   someone, even if there are great qualities or merits in that, you
>   still have a strong hatred towards it.

Is **"Hate me, hate my dog"** OKAY ?  Like the following example:

> You cost me a golden opportunity to be admitted into Harvard
>   University years ago. Now even though you are willing to give me a big
>   sum of money, I will not forgive you. As the idiom goes: hate me, hate my dog.

Comment: Could you please include a link to your source(s)?

Comment: source to the definition ?   Just edited the quesiton.

Comment: As you see it, what is the dog in your Harvard example?

Comment: *You killed my father, prepare to die.*

Comment: To  Clare: maybe the "hate me, hate my dog" in my Harvard example could be replaced with:   "As the idiom goes:  hate me, hate my dog" .

Comment: To  Clare: dog is the money , I think.

Comment: *... I will not forgive you. As the saying goes, "To err is human, but God is dead."*

Comment: Fun fact: "Love me and love my dog" appears as a proverb in the 1678 edition of John Ray, [_A Collection of English Proverbs_](https://books.google.com/books?id=rnlQoxh95VMC&pg=PA63&dq=%22One+year+of+joy,+another+of+comfort,+and+all+the+rest+of+content%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yok5VOHUKcX5iwKY74GICA#v=onepage&q=%22love%20my%20dog%22&f=false). Ray says it comes from a French source: "Qui aime Jean aime son chien," although he also cites "Spesse volte si ha rispetto al cane per il padrone." People have been making relationships conditional on affection for their dogs for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfgang Mieder, *A Dictionary of American Proverbs* (1992) lists one dog-centric proverb that recasts the "Love me, love my dog" saying in a negative form: **Strike my dog and you strike me.** Here is the entry for that expression in Mieder's dictionary:

> Strike my dog and you strike me. ***Rec[orded] dist[ribution]:*** Ala[bama], G[eorgi]a, ***1st cit[ation]:*** 1588 *Discourse Upon the Present State of France*. ***20c[entury] coll[ections]:*** *O[xford] D[ictionary of] E[nglish] P[roverbs]* [1970] 781, Stevenson[, *The Macmillan Book of Proverbs, Maxims and Familiar Phrases* (1948)] 607:6.

Since the only two places where Mieder identifies recent instances of the proverb are the contiguous Deep South states of Alabama and Georgia—although it appears as far back as 1588 in an English book about France—the expression is evidently not in widespread use today.

Answer (score 0):

I think a pretty good opposite response to "love me, love my dog" would be "F*ck you and the horse you rode in on." Naturally, it's not polite, but everyone has probably heard it before.

Comment: If the OP is British we can say *Bugger* and have it be less offensive (or at least to American speakers)!